# Error creating extension postgis; - everything else is installed and appears to work fine

Tags: postgresql, centos, postgis, centos6

i am running postgresql on a centos VM and had no troubles with the installation of everything including postgis. from the terminal i do the following:

```
# su - postgres
# psql database_name
# CREATE EXTENSION post_gis;
```

at this point i receive this error:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/rtpostgis-2.1.so": libhdf5.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

however, if you navigate to that folder the file is there. i also know that i have libhdf5 as well. so not sure what i missed. any ideas? i have searched here and other places but nothing seems to pinpoint my issue.

Comment: It's `postgis` not `post_gis`. What's `rtpostgis`? How *exactly* did you install everything, and from where?

Comment: my guides and instructions i have been following say to type post_gis ... anyway neither work. i installed everything using yum install after i setup the CentOS-Base.repo to exclude its default repositories.

Comment: From which repositories? "using yum" can mean anything. You're not providing a great deal of information here.

Comment: What guides use `post_gis`? Which version of CentOS did you install to?

Comment: @CraigRinger `rtpostgis-*.so` is part of PostGIS 2.x for the raster type, and is required for `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`.